# Exiting an Android application

Tags: android

I have developed an application and there are many activities in this project.
In setting activity, I place one exit button, on click event of that exit button I want to exit whole application. So what should I do for that?

Comment: Alot of answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+exit+application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are calling activity B from an activity A.and C from B

A->B

use startactivityforresult from A

and again B->C

use startactivityforresult from B

and when you want to exit from C then setResult(i.e. RESULT_OK) and finish C.and in OnActivityResult() in B,check if resultcode == RESULT_OK then again finish B and setresult(RESULT_OK) for A.same procedure will follow to finish A.

this will exit you from the application.and application will start from A not from C.

Comment: but there are lots of activity. so how can i handle whole project

Comment: actually android doesn't exit application,it handles from its own way,what we can do,exit from all application,by this process.else you can hide your application by launching home page.  moveTaskToBack(true);

Answer (score 1):

I think [finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) is what you are looking for.

Comment: but finish is exit only current activity

Answer (score 0):

As a bad example - u can create your own broadcast 'com.example.KILL_ACTIVITIES' and send it in onBackPressed method. So, all your activities must be registered to this broadcast and call finish() when receive that broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

"Android" programs aren't supposed to have an EXIT button. See any app that comes pre-installed in your device and check if any of them actually have an EXIT button. Exit makes no sense. It just ends up giving a sense of false security to the user.

Comment: [More](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon) like minded people here..

Answer (score 0):

Just write this code in your application

moveTaskToBack(true);

And you will be thrown out to main android desktop..

Answer (score 0):

Use this to end an Application 
    System.exit(0);