# Android:Exit in application

Tags: android, button, exit

I Have developed a android application. In that application I have exit button, I want to exit from my application when I press the EXIT BUTTON. please someone give me a sample code or a tutorial link.

Comment: follow this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401692/exit-android-application/5401822#5401822

Answer (score 1):

Read [(When to Include an Exit Button in Android Apps (Hint: Never))](http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2010/05/when-to-include-exit-button-in-android.html), this article explain you what you need to do and what need not.

Some extract

> So, when should your app include an exit button?
>
> **The Short Answer**
>
> Never.
>
> **The Long Answer**
>
> Your app doesn't need an exit button. It really doesn't. Arguments to
>   the contrary can generally be summarized as:
>
> - Users expect it.
> - It's a way to let users say "stop doing everything and stop consuming juice".

Answer (score 0):

call `finish()` on the `onClick()` method of your button

Comment: when i call finish() method within app, it exits only my current page. but i want to exit from my application when i press the Exit button.

Comment: You have to call finish() of your main(first) activity i.e. the activity whose category is of `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` type in manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Set finish() method on your button click event like..

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    finish();
             }
      });
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want close specific activity use finish or if you want to remove
         stack from Android process use the following code:

```
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            super.onDestroy();



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

    this.setContentView(R.layout.layoutxml); 

    this.ExitButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.close); 

    this.ExitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

    @Override 

    public void onClick(View v) { 

    finish(); // for stopping Current Activity 

    } 

    });

    // add this line forStoping Entire Application  to Close 
    @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
    // closing Entire Application
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            super.onDestroy();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I strongly discourage this. In a normal application you shouldn't kill the process. Android will do this for you!

Comment: Hello i asked solutions just i given advise , i am not encouraging that .